# Ruby on rails & Couchrest model: use existing views

Tags: couchdb, couchrest

I'm having some issues with my couchDB and the couchrest model.

I have a running system with existing views in my couchDB (they are working fine). Now I want to use them in a ruby on rails project with the couch rest model.
I want to define them with:

```
design do
    view :by_name
end
```

Everytime I run the code the designdocument is overwritten with default views from the couchrest model.

Does anybody know how to just "use" them, without changing anything in the designdocument of the database?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Couchrest Model Docs: http://www.couchrest.info/model/view_objects.html

It has a configuration option: auto_update_design_doc, which is set true by default.

When a view is requested a quick GET for the design document will be sent to ensure it is up to date with the latest version defined in the model.

Setting this option to false so that you can use existing views. But you need to deal with view updating by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've been studying the CouchRestModel for a week or so and I think the best way for your to "use" the existing design views is to define them in the model.

As you can see in http://www.couchrest.info/model/view_objects.html , you can write your own map and reduce functions. This will not "use" the existing design views but it will overwrite with a function of your own, which can be the exact same design view you had previously written.

Example:

```
design do
    view :by_title,
        :map =>
            "function(doc) {
                if (doc['type'] == 'Post' && doc['title'] != null) {
                    emit(doc['title'], 1);
                }
            }",
        :reduce =>
            "function(keys, values, rereduce) {
                return sum(values);
            }"
end
```